# Expand Template in a Function Extension

Tags: mediawiki

I am creating a `FunctionHook` extension (`{{#foo:bar}}` in wikitext), which according to the documentation has the input parameters with templates expanded, and the output should be wikitext.

The problem is I'm wanting part of the output to add a template to the page. But it's coming in as the raw wikitext for the template, because template expanding has already happened. I know there's a `$parser->recursiveTagParse($output, $frame)` command available, but when I do that, templates get expanded, as to link wikitext, which breaks external links (`[http://google.com google]` becomes `<a href="http://google.com">google</a>`, which gets parsed again into `&lt;a href="<a href="http://www.google.com">http://www.google.com</a>"&gt;google&lt;/a&gt;`)

So is there a command that can be called from within a FunctionHook extension to expand templates without expanding other wikitext?

Code Sample:

```
$wgHooks['ParserFirstCallInit'][] = 'fooBar_Setup';
$wgHooks['LanguageGetMagic'][] = 'fooBar_Magic';

function fooBar_Setup(&$parser) {
  $parser->setFunctionHook('fb', 'fooBar_Render');
  return true;
}
function fooBar_Magic(&$magicWords, $lang) {
  $magicWords['fb'] = array(0, 'fb', 'foobar');
  return true;
}
function fooBar_Render($parser, $param1) {
  $output = '{{prettyOutput|'.$param1.'}} [http://www.google.com Search the web]';
  $output = $parser->recursiveTagParse($output);
  return $output;
}
```

With this code, if I run that as-is, the template (`prettyOutput`) gets included as expected, but the Google link gets double-parsed and becomes `&lt;a href="<a href="http://www.google.com">http://www.google.com</a>"&gt;Search the web&lt;/a&gt;`. If I take out the `recursiveTagParse` line, the template stays as a literal `{{prettyOutput|myInput}}` on the page, but the external link works properly.

Answer (score 2):

Generally a parser *function hook* ({{#foo:param}}) returns wikitext markup, while a *tag hook* (text) returns HTML.

From a function hook, you should only need to return 'something something {{mytemplate}}' and the rest of the parser should expand the template for you -- exactly what it sounds like you want.

Can you give a specific example of what you're doing -- preferably a complete, runnable code example -- that demonstrates what's being expanded that you *don't* want expanded?

Answer (score 0):

If you just return wiki text from your parser function, it is only partly parsed. For example templates will not be rendered.

Your approach of calling the parser yourself is correct. But you need to tell the parser that the returned output is already parsed:

```
return array( $parser->recursiveTagParse($output), 
              'noparse' => true, 'isHTML' => true );
```